# How to set the text box color as like as google

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development. How can I style the textbox and textbox color to be similar to the Google one in the image below?

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.venu{
  width: 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px  ridge #dadada;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background: url(2.png) top right no-repeat;
  background-position:right;
  background-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 45%;
  position:fixed;
  top:51%;
  bottom:60%;
  left:30%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="venv">
```

Comment: So you wan't a icon? I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: in your html you refer to an input with class venv but in your css you style a class venu. the class name must match. Adapt your code accordingly please

Comment: People who make the effort and try to help you expect you to react to the suggestions. They have invested time and research, so it's a question of respect to do that. Apart from that, not reacting makes this whole question and answers so much less useful for others when researching on SO.

Comment: You declare the `.venu` class but you are using the `.nenv` class. Does this typo is only on the question or in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of what I think you expect. It is building off what you already had.

I just looked up a microphone icon, but you are free to use whatever icon that you want

```css
.venu {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px  ridge #dadada;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding:10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.venu:focus {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0.5px gray;
  outline: none;
}

img {
  width:25px;
  position:fixed;
  left: 360px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform:scale(1.05);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="venu"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-messaging-productivity-1/128/speaker-512.png">
```